# Transactional publication and database mirroring considerations

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication, mirroring

I've recently taken over a project, and with it comes 2 backends. 1st is the production services backend and the 2nd is a reporting service backend. Both of which are 2008r2 instances.

The production database is mirrored to a Dr site. It is high safety no witness. The principal database has a transactional publication setup that serves to the reporting instances pull subscription.

I'm trying to better understand under what circumstances do I have to remove a mirror, pause/resume a mirror and delete publication and/or subscription.

Here are some use cases I'm curious about. Generally because of major and minor service releases

1. New or updated schemas.
2. New tables/columns.
3. New or modified mappings and permissions.

And I'm sure I'm missing other stuff.

Any help would be appreciated.